# JavaFX on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, oracle, netbeans

On Lubuntu 18.04, I have NetBeans 11, Oracle JDK 12, Open JDK 11, and openjfx installed. Attempting to make any javafx project to run.

If I open a javafx sample, with jdk 12 selected, netbeans activates javafx, downloads some stuff, but it still cannot find javafx libraries. I have no idea if those libraries are anywhere on the system, but on their website it is stated they should be part of the jdk. This is the first question, how is Oracle javafx used?

If I open my old javafx project with jdk 11 selected, I can find openjfx jars and make the project compile. However, when I try to run it, it reports that javafx runtime components are missing, even though i pointed to them in the run tab of project settings. Did anyone make this scenario work, and how?